# Calculate time span with different patterns

Tags: sql, sql-server

The calculation of a time span with gaps and islands was already discussed.
But what about different patterns of time spans present?

The present data is a combination of gaps between time spans and contiguous time spans. These are available in different forms.
`ID` 1 has 5 time spans of which 4 lie within the first time span from `2000-08-08` to `2019-03-31` but for `ID` 2 the time spans are present in such a way that the next time span in the next line falls within the end date of the following line. `ID 3` has a gap between the first enddate and the following startdate.

My code works just for `ID` 2 and 3.
How do I find the time span for `ID` 1 as well?

In exactly this case my code does not work.

The problem occurs with `ID` 1 as the code is not able to solve it with 1 iteration, because the data is present in a different way.

| id | startdate | enddate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2000-08-08 | 2019-03-31 |
| 1 | 2007-06-08 | 2007-09-09 |
| 1 | 2008-02-08 | 2011-08-04 |
| 1 | 2012-08-01 | 2012-09-20 |
| 1 | 2018-02-01 | 2019-03-31 |
| 2 | 2013-02-18 | 2019-03-28 |
| 2 | 2018-04-12 | 2020-07-28 |
| 3 | 2015-01-11 | 2015-04-02 |
| 3 | 2016-02-08 | 2021-11-22 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sizLBdE5)

My code:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    startdate,
    enddate,
    CASE
      WHEN LAG(enddate) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY startdate) >= DATEADD(day, -1, startdate) THEN 0
      ELSE 1
    END AS new_grp
  FROM tab1
), cte2 AS (
  SELECT
    cte1.*,
    SUM(new_grp) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY startdate) AS grp_num
  FROM cte1
)
SELECT
  id,
  MIN(startdate) AS startdate,
  MAX(enddate) AS enddate
FROM cte2
GROUP BY id, grp_num
ORDER BY id, startdate;
```

But when I want to derive the time span for `ID` 1 it does need 4 iterations - so the classical gaps and islands approach is not feasible.

What I expect:

| id | startdate | enddate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2000-08-08 | 2019-03-31 |
| 2 | 2013-02-18 | 2020-07-28 |
| 3 | 2015-01-11 | 2015-04-02 |
| 3 | 2016-02-08 | 2021-11-22 |

Comment: What's the actual question? What patterns are you talking about and why would this be a gaps and islands problem? It looks like you want the MIN and MAX values per group

Comment: You mean you want to merge overlapping time spans? I'm not sure it's a classic gaps and islands problem

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos But this would not work for ID3 as ID3 has two disjunct time spans.

Comment: The first step in solving a SQL problem is expressing it in English, without resorting to iterations or looping. There's no problem description here, we have to guess from the result data. You never said you want to *merge* intervals, you talked about patterns, gaps and no explanation of the results

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I will revise. Sorry for that.

Comment: What you want is essentially an OVERLAPS operation or rather, aggregation. That's available in one way or another for spatial operations. Databases with more advanced temporal support also include time-based aggregations, but not SQL Server by itself. The streaming support in Azure SQL may be able to help

Comment: This means you need a way to aggregate overlapping internals. I'm pretty sure someone would have written a way to do this, even as an answer to one of Itzik Ben-Gan's SQL quizzes, or Joe Celko's articles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take max(enddte) in preceding rows.

Change

```
CASE
      WHEN LAG(enddate) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY startdate) >= DATEADD(day, -1, startdate) THEN 0
      ELSE 1
    END AS new_grp
```

with

```
    CASE
      WHEN MAX(enddate) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY startdate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
          >= DATEADD(day, -1, startdate) 
      THEN 0
      ELSE 1
    END AS new_grp
```

Query example (from your fiddle)

```
WITH cte1 AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    startdate,
    enddate,
    CASE
      WHEN MAX(enddate) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY startdate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
          >= DATEADD(day, -1, startdate) 
      THEN 0
      ELSE 1
    END AS new_grp
  FROM tab1
), cte2 AS (
  SELECT
    cte1.*,
    SUM(new_grp) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY startdate) AS grp_num
  FROM cte1
)
SELECT
  id,
  MIN(startdate) AS startdate,
  MAX(enddate) AS enddate
FROM cte2
GROUP BY id, grp_num
ORDER BY id, startdate;
```